# How to sort many numeric columns in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have 72 columns of numbers in Excel and I need each of them sorted from lowest to highest numbers. Keeping rows together doesn't matter. How to I sort all my columns at once? My need is to identify the lowest 10 outliers and the highest 10 outliers and exclude them from average, standard deviation, etc.

Comment: Do you really want them sorted or just find the average of all the numbers minuse the 20 outliers?  Getting to the end is a simple equation.

Answer (score 0):

Use AVERAGEIFS and use LARGE and SMALL to find the outliers to exclude:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:I34,A1:I34,"<"&LARGE(A1:I34,10),A1:I34,">"&SMALL(A1:I34,10))
```

And the StdDev:

```
=STDEV.P(IF((A1:I34<LARGE(A1:I34,10))*(A1:I34>SMALL(A1:I34,10)),A1:I34))
```

This formula may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Where `A1:I34` is your dataset.

[image]